# SKSpriteNode (with texture) with wrong orientation

Tags: swift, uiimageview, sprite-kit, orientation, skspritenode

I have a `SpriteKit` project with which I'm using `Swift` to take an image or chose an image and display it. I know how to take or chose the image, but the problem is when I'm displaying it. Whenever I was displaying it, it would have the wrong orientation. So I used this code to orientate it:

```
let orientedImage = UIImage(CGImage: chosenImage.CGImage!, scale: 1, orientation: chosenImage.imageOrientation)
```

This worked very well on a `UIImageView`, but didn't work on a `SKSpriteNode`. This is the code I have for displaying the image on a `UIImageView` and on a `SKSpriteNode`:

```
let imageview = UIImageView(image: orientedImage) // Displaying the image on a UIImageView
self.view!.addSubview(imageview)
let texture = SKTexture(image: orientedImage)
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture) // Displaying the image on a SKSpriteNode
self.addChild(node)
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work on a `SKSpriteNode`, but works on a `UIImageView`. Please help... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So actually you are using only SKSpriteNode in this project, and the UIImageView is a part of another project? I mean using both at the same time will be weird (or at least I don't see the purpose of that)... Also, define "wrong orientation". Can you upload the image you are using?

Comment: I was using a UIImageView just for testing. The image I'm using is just a random Image from cameraRoll

Comment: Okay, but I need something which can replicate the issue. You know, to show me what you are considering as "correct orientation" vs "wrong orientation".

Comment: @Whirlwind Good news I just found a solution to my problem by redirecting it to a cropView which orientates it correctly. Do you still want me to upload an image or do I just delete the question (or let it be)?

Comment: Well I am just about to try what you are saying , so I will figure out what was the issue. You can do with your question what you want :)

Comment: @Whirlwind Good luck! :) It's nice that you try people's problem and try to figure them out ;)

Comment: Actually, it is unclear how do you create the `chosenImage`. But there is nothing wrong with `SKSpriteNode`. `SKSpriteNode(texture:)` just creates a sprite from texture. What you will see would be the same as how the actual texture looks like.

Comment: Seems like `UIImageView` respects an image's orientation metadata (which is rotated because of the camera sensor's orientation), while `SKTexture` ignores it. I didn't find a solution to this besides rotating the `SKSpriteNode` to compensate.